# Jmeter- how to include external .p12 SSL certificate

Tags: jmeter

```
exception Jmeter throws- 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:422)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.h(qc.java:714)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:831)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.startHandshake(qc.java:828)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:553)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:412)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.LazySchemeSocketFactory.connectSocket(LazySchemeSocketFactory.java:97)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.open(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:114)
```

Is there any specific Java version need to be used?
Jmeter version is - 3.1

Answer (score 1):

1. Just add the next lines to *system.properties* file (located in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12    
   javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/your/certificate.p12
   javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your_certificate_password_here
   ```

   Another option is providing the aforementioned properties via -D command-line argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/your/certificate.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your_certificate_password_here
   ```

   This is more convenient for unattended executions, i.e. using [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) servers
2. Restart JMeter to pick the properties up
3. Now JMeter will be using your client certificate for requests encryption

See [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates) for more details.

Alternatively you can use [SSL Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SSL_Manager), however personally I consider using system properties more convenient.

Comment: thanx for the response.I tried the steps as you mentioned avax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12    
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/your/certificate.p12
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your_certificate_password_here.... but no success still getting the error as : Response code: Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Remote host closed connection during handshake.

Comment: I used absolute path to `p12` file in `javax.net.ssl.keyStore`, but I got file not found error after I executed test suite.